# How to get resolution from map in open openlayers

Tags: openlayers

i want to get resolution from map when user zoom in or zoom out map.

how to get resolution from map in open openlayers.

we try this but not getting resolutions from map.

```
var resolutions = this.map.getView().getResolutions();
```

Comment: It is [`getResolution`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#getResolution), not `getResolutions`

Comment: i try this but not getting resolutions its showing --
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current resolution use `getResolution()`, without the S.
If you want to get it when the map is zoomed, you can use a listener for the event [`moveend`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_MapEvent-MapEvent.html#event:moveend).